Cannot Figure Out Transform Constraints
I'm tearing my hair out trying to do something that I believe should be dead-simple, and I can't figure out what I am missing.
Assume three bone-chain in sequence: A, B, C. They are not connected, but in a parent-chain and floating.
I want to control this chain like an IK limb. The restriction is I can not modify the original armature at all. No reparenting, no new bones, etc.
So, I create another rig with an IK Limb set up with corresponding controller bones.
Here is an example. The green bones are the original armature. The blue one is the controller armature.

So the task is simple, the green bones should be able to follow the transforming positions and rotations of their corresponding blue bones.
No, Child-Of constraints are not possible here, because the green bones are parented to each other as I said. So when a child green bone is moved to follow a blue bone, and then its own parent is also moved, this causes it to move out of synchronization.

So we can try a Copy Location and Copy Rotation in offset mode, so that the green bone moves together with the blue bone, and when the blue bone rotates, the green bone will experience the same transformation.

But this does not work. When setting up the Copy Rotation constraint, even though the Blue Bone hasn't moved at all, the corresponding green bone has mutated its rotation away from pointing forward, as shown.
It appears that Blender is bugged, because performing this same constraint setup (Copy Loc + Copy Rot) onto 2 cubes with the offset mode as object constraints creates the desired behavior perfectly.

Share your file. https://blend-exchange.com/

What are you talking about? Could you edit the question and explain what it actually is that you are trying to do and why? Please provide screenshots and pictures, .blend file if possible. Provide context as well - what is this for? Why do you need it? Why are you doing it this way(whatever way it is)? At the moment it's not clear what your problem is because you have not described what you are trying to do and this question is not likely to get any meaningful answers.

I'm flabbergasted. I wrote entire paragraphs describing what I'm doing, and the problems encountered doing it.
If you want a blend file or screenshots, that's fine, but please do not insinuate I did not explain what I am doing, because I did precisely that.

As R-800 says, please share your file

You seem to have set up a lot of very strange rules and given yourself a nearly impossible situation. Why do the green bones have to be parented to eachother if they aren't going to use eachother's transforms at all? Why can't you modify the blue armature?
